# getting error in bonfire while starting

Tags: bonfire

I just installed bonefire in my system but I am getting following errors in that.`

```
  [Mon Dec 21 11:30:07.428428 2015] [:error] [pid 3241] [client 192.168.50.74:42003] SoftException in Application.cpp:350: UID of script "/var/www/html/bonfire/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
  [Mon Dec 21 11:30:07.428502 2015] [core:error] [pid 3241] [client 192.168.50.74:42003] End of script output before headers: index.php
```

`